"NameError: name 'JoinStyleRound' is not defined" error when offsetting feature of line type geometry with PyQGIS
I'm trying to offset a feature with line-type geometry, I found a suggestion to work based on the QgsGeometry.offsetCurve() method, see https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.34/core/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.offsetCurve.
However, I'm having problems with the function parameters.
from qgis.core import QgsProject

p = QgsProject.instance()
line = p.mapLayersByName('line')[0]

for feature in line.getFeatures():
    if str(feature['ID']) == '1':
        new_feature = feature.geometry().offsetCurve(5, 8, JoinStyleRound, 2)

When running the code, I get the following error:

(NameError: name 'JoinStyleRound' is not defined)



JoinStyleRound was part of an enum located in Qgis.JoinStyle. From what I can see in QGIS version 3.34 it's now called Round.
If you work in the Python Console of QGIS (Ctrl+Alt+P), you can find it below:
from qgis.core import Qgis

Qgis.JoinStyle.Round # <JoinStyle.Round: 1>

So your snippet will become:
from qgis.core import QgsProject, Qgis

p = QgsProject.instance()
line = p.mapLayersByName('line')[0]

for feature in line.getFeatures():
    if str(feature['ID']) == '1':
        new_feature = feature.geometry().offsetCurve(5, 8, Qgis.JoinStyle.Round, 2)

Now, I guess your code won't work as expected after these changes.
offsetCurve() returns the new QgsGeometry so I imagine you want to change the geometry of your feature with this new calculated geometry.
Something like this seems more logical to me (but I can be wrong depending on what you want to achieve) (not tested but you have the idea)
from qgis.core import QgsProject, Qgis

p = QgsProject.instance()
line = p.mapLayersByName('line')[0]

with edit(line):
    for feature in line.getFeatures():
        if str(feature['ID']) == '1':
            new_geom = feature.geometry().offsetCurve(5, 8, Qgis.JoinStyle.Round, 2)
            feature.setGeometry(new_geom)
            line.updateFeature(feature)

